# SQLite join selection from the same table using reference from another table

Tags: database, sqlite

I have two tables:

table: points

```
|key_id | name | x | y |
------------------------
|1      | A    |10 |20 |
|2      | A_1  |11 |21 |
|3      | B    |30 |40 |
|4      | B_1  |31 |42 |
```

table: pairs

```
|f_key_p1 | f_key_p2 |
----------------------
|1        | 2        |
|3        | 4        |
```

Table 'pairs' defines which rows in table 'points' should be paired.
How can I query database to select paired rows?
My desired query result would be like this:

```
|name_1|x_1|x_2|name_2|x_2|y_2|
-------------------------------
|A     |10 |20 |A_1   |11 |21 |
|B     |30 |40 |B_1   |31 |41 |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just join from `points` to `pairs` and from `pairs` again to `points`. E.g. like this:

```
SELECT
p1.name AS name_1, p1.x AS x_1, p1.y AS y_1,
p2.name AS name_2, p2.x AS x_2, p2.y AS y_2
FROM points as p1
INNER JOIN pairs ON (p1.key_id = pairs.f_key_p1)
INNER JOIN points AS p2 ON (pairs.f_key_p2 = p2.key_id);
```

Using the `INNER JOIN` (abbr. `JOIN`) combines rows only if there is a match in both tables.

Answer (score 1):

```
select p1.name name_1, p1.x x_1, p1.y y_1, p2.name name_2, p2.x x_2, p2.y y_2
from points p1 join pairs p on p1.key_id = p.f_key_p1 
               join points p2 on p2.key_id = p.f_key_p2
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I decided to recognize thpani's answer because it's clearer and he needs reputation score. Best regards.